# Using Ubuntu Text-Based

Tags: command-line, gnome

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with GNOME. Is there a way to unload GNOME and use Ubuntu look like Arch Linux installation process. With colors but only console screen. Directly from CLI.

Using Ubuntu like this: [Example][image: Only Console Screen]

I know that I can install Arch Linux and don't install any desktop environment. But installing Arch Linux is hard and Ubuntu have a bigger package repository.

( Just unloading GNOME and have access to load it again would be better, but I'm ready to remove it too :D )

Comment: I'm not using Ubuntu Server. This is my personal computer Jos.

Comment: Removing the desktop and all of its dependencies pretty much comes down to installing Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Thank you Melebius! I'm now using CTRL+ALT+F* to switch between tty2 tty3 tty4... and CTRL+ALT+F1 for GNOME. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with 20.04.1 LTS (meaning all your harware works)
then install the **SERVER** version of 20.04.01 LTS [here](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/?_ga=2.195024932.849085776.1602058008-1725102499.1602058008)

Comment: No server is too modified and look like non-text-based.

Comment: Server has the same apt repositories as Desktop and you won't know the difference except for the absence of the DE. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F

Comment: DE's are bad idc